# 1D k-epsilon turbulence model in a turbidity current

Tags: finite-difference, advection-diffusion

I am trying to implement a 1D k-$\varepsilon$ turbulent model for a turbidity current, hence the conservation equation for $c$. I'm solving for the variables $u,c,k$ and $\varepsilon$. The remaining terms are parameters.
$$
\newcommand{\cmu}{c_{\mu}}
\newcommand{\cmuc}{c_{\mu c}}
\newcommand{\dervz}[1]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial z}}
\newcommand{\eddyvis}{\cmu \frac{k^2}{\varepsilon}}
\newcommand{\eddyvisC}{\cmuc \frac{\hat{k}^2}{\hat{\varepsilon}}}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial u }{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left[ \left( \nu + \cmu \frac{k^2}{\varepsilon} \right) \frac{\partial u }{\partial z} \right]
+ \frac{\rho_s - \rho_w}{\rho_w} c g_x
$$

$$
 \frac{\partial c}{\partial t} =
 v_s \dervz{c} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left[ \left( \nu + \cmuc \frac{k^2}{\varepsilon} \right) \dervz{c} \right] 
$$

$$
 \frac{\partial k}{\partial t} =
  \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  \left[ \left( \nu + \frac{\cmu}{\sigma_k} \frac{k^2}{\varepsilon} \right) \dervz{k} \right] + \eddyvis \left(\dervz{U}\right)^2 - \varepsilon 
  + \frac{\rho - \rho_w}{\rho_w} g_z \frac{1}{\sigma} \eddyvisC \dervz{c}
$$

$$
 \frac{\partial \varepsilon}{\partial t} =
  \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  \left[ \left( \nu + \frac{\cmu}{\sigma_{\varepsilon}} \frac{k^2}{\varepsilon} \right) \dervz{\varepsilon} \right] 
  + c_{\varepsilon 1} \frac{\varepsilon}{k} 
  \left( \eddyvis \left(\dervz{u}\right)^2  + c_{\varepsilon 3} 
  \frac{\rho - \rho_w}{\rho_w} g_z \frac{1}{\sigma} \eddyvisC \dervz{c} \right) - C_{\varepsilon 2} \frac{ \varepsilon^2}{k}
$$

So far, I am using finite difference. Upwind scheme for the first order derivatives. Because the paramter $v_s$ is positive, concentration travels downwards at a speed $v_s$, I'm implementing the upwind scheme as:
$$
\frac{c^{i+1}_n - c^{i}_n}{\Delta z}
$$
for the node $i$. I also use the same upwind scheme for all the first-order derivative terms, i.e. also the terms inside the diffusion terms, which are nonlinear. For the linear diffusion terms, I apply second order central difference. For the time integration, I use a Crank-Nicholson method treating all terms implicitly.

The boundary conditions are complex. I'm using a standard wall function, using the log law at a node far from the wall. Using the log law, I also impose a gradient boundary condition because the log law adds the shear velocity as a unknown, hence the additional equation/condition. For 
$k$ and $\varepsilon$ I use conditions that depend on the shear velocity. That's for one side of the domain, at the other side, sufficiently far, I use zero value conditions.

I'm not seeing much success with this implementation, should I use different discretization schemes for the diffusion and the advective terms? Should I use a different method altogether such as Finite Volume? What confuses me are the diffusion terms. Which discretization should I use there?

With regards to the time discretization. Should I treat some terms explicitely? The source terms are nonlinear as well.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Response to the first comment

Sorry I was not clear there. The model blows up for certain initial values of the concentration (too much acceleration), although that might have to do with the wall function implementation I think. Another issue that I had  were the initial conditions for $k$ and $\varepsilon$. I'll explain. The initial conditions for the velocity and concentration do not span the entire domain. They have positive values only for one tenth of the lower part of the domain, where I implement the wall function boundary condition, eventually, they will diffuse upwards. However, they will not do so if the values for $k$ and $\varepsilon$ are zero above where $u$ and $c$ are. This is because they are in the diffusion term and I think because of the upwind scheme, which assumes the wave travels downwards.

Comment: What are you out for? Since turbulence is a 3D phenomenon, I don't think that $\kappa-\epsilon$ models make any sense in 1D.

Comment: It's a one dimensional velocity profile, where we have neglected the velocity components that are not the streamwise components. There's still turbulence since there are velocities gradients.

Comment: I don't think this is enough for turbulence (models) to have a velocity gradient only in streamwise direction. E.g., the basic models for turbulence, like the $\kappa-\epsilon$ model, base on Prandtl's *mixing length* model, that bases on $\partial \bar u /\partial y$, i.e., the gradient of the mean flow in transversal direction.

Comment: There are no velocity component in the transversal direction, but there are  velocity gradients. I typed them as $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$.

Comment: USe crank nicolson coz its more stable and conserves mass